# Prove rationality of a number by proof by contradiction

Tags: solution-verification, rationality-testing

So I was going through proof of irrationality of $\sqrt2$ and tried to construct a proof whether $\sqrt4$ is rational by proof of contradiction.

Proof: (By Contradiction)

For the purposes of contradiction assume $\sqrt4$ is irrational that means:

$\sqrt4$ can't be written in the form of $\frac{m}{n}$ where gcd(m,n) = 1

So $\sqrt4$ $\ne$ $\frac{m}{n}$

i.e 4 $\ne$ $\frac{m^2}{n^2}$

so 4*$n^2$ $\ne$ $m^2$

but then I am struck what to do? Please help me out.

P.S. I know we can easily write $\sqrt4$ as $\frac{2}{1}$ and that proves that it is rational but how would I go on proving by this approach.

Comment: $4n^2=m^2$ has solutions, for example $n=1$ and $m=2$. This is the desired contradiction.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer.